# Disable HomeMenuItems in ListViewMenu

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm creating a menu in Xamarin.
I would like to disable all the menu items that are **MenuItemType.None**. This items should be disabled/skipped for the user selection. (the items with **MenuItemType.None should "act like a header"**)

I have the following code:

```
    MainPage RootPage { get => Application.Current.MainPage as MainPage; }
    List<HomeMenuItem> menuItems;
    object lastSelectedItem = null;

    public MenuPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        menuItems = new List<HomeMenuItem>
        {
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.None, Title = "N" },
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.A, Title="A" },
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.B, Title="B" },
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.C, Title="C" },
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.D, Title="D" },
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.E, Title="E" },
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.F, Title="F" }
        };
        

        ListViewMenu.ItemsSource = menuItems;      

        ListViewMenu.SelectedItem = menuItems[1];
        ListViewMenu.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.SelectedItem == null)
                return;

            var id = (int)((HomeMenuItem)e.SelectedItem).Id;

            if (id == (int)MenuItemType.None)
                return;

            await RootPage.NavigateFromMenu(id);
        };
    }
```

EDIT1:
I tried like this, but I don't know how to access the collections item:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < ((List<HomeMenuItem>)ListViewMenu.ItemsSource).Count; i++)
        {
            if (((List<HomeMenuItem>)ListViewMenu.ItemsSource)[i].Id == MenuItemType.None)
            {
                ?.isEnabled = false;
            }
        }
```

EDIT2: MenuPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Sts.Views.MenuPage"
             Title="Menu">
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <ListView x:Name="ListViewMenu"
                    HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid Padding="10">
                            <Image Source="" /><Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="20"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have?

Comment: Please post the XAML for ListViewMenu

Comment: Hi, I don't know how to disable a certain list item

Comment: I don’t know what you think “disable” should do.  Your code already ignores taps on those rows.  What else specifically do you want it to do differently for those rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Liyun Zhang - MSFT: Unfortunately the e.SelectedItem is just read-only

I managed to get it working this way:

```
int lastSelectedItemIndex = -1;//global
...
            ListViewMenu.ItemsSource = menuItems;

            ListViewMenu.SelectedItem = menuItems[1];
            lastSelectedItemIndex = 1;

            ListViewMenu.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) =>
            {
                int id = e.SelectedItem==null ? -1 : (int)((HomeMenuItem)e.SelectedItem).Id;
                if (id==-1 || id == (int)MenuItemType.None)
                {
                    ListViewMenu.ItemsSource = null;

                    ListViewMenu.ItemsSource = menuItems;

                    ListViewMenu.SelectedItem = menuItems[lastSelectedItemIndex];
                    return;
                }
                
                lastSelectedItemIndex = e.SelectedItemIndex;
                await RootPage.NavigateFromMenu(id);
            };
```

Comment: Sorry for my caseless, you can use the `(sender as ListView).SelectedItem = null;`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no a such method can disable one item of the ListView.

> the items with MenuItemType.None should "act like a header"

You can put the item with MenuItemType.None into the [ListView's header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#headers-and-footers). And make the other items as the listview's item source.

In addtion, you can also set the SelectedItem as null when the user selects the items with MenuItemType.None. Such as:

```
        ListViewMenu.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.SelectedItem == null)
                return;

            var id = (int)((HomeMenuItem)e.SelectedItem).Id

            if (id == (int)MenuItemType.None)
              {
                (sender as ListView).SelectedItem = null;
                return;
              }
            await RootPage.NavigateFromMenu(id);
        };
```